# Share functionality of a class between two or more libraries with pure virtual functions

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

It's ok,

having:

```
class A
{
    virtual x() = 0;
    virtual y() = 0;
}

class B
{
    virtual x() = 0;
    virtual z() = 0;
}

class C : A , B
{
    x();
    y();
    z();
}
```

to share instances of class C with two libraries whose one knows only of A and another knows only of B?

Like:

Library 1:

```
#include <a>

A* a = function_in_the_core_that_creates_a_C_and_retrieves_it();
a->x();
a->y();
```

Library 1:

```
#include <b>

B* b = function_in_the_core_that_creates_a_C_and_retrieves_it();
b->x();
b->z();
```

I'm asking this because I wonder if the compiler will have problems to resolve the functions since the libraries don't have a full knowledge of the ancestry of C.

EDIT:

**function_in_the_core_that_creates_a_C_and_retrieves_it()** is supposed to return a C* not a C. I thought that that was clear since we are talking about virtual functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should make the code compile. C is privately inheriting A and B, so this example isn't going to run. `class C : public A , public B` is the corrected declaration for `C`. You are also missing return types for the functions.

Either `function_in_the_core_that_creates_a_C_and_retrieves_it` will return a `B*`, which will then conform to the full ancestry of `B` and work as a `B` for all intents and purposes - or it will return a `C*`, in which case you will have to provide a full declaration of `C` in order for the assignment to work without an explicit cast. You cannot have `C` just forward declared to do this.

So, you're either returning a pointer to `B` in which case there is no problem - or a pointer to `C` where you will need to provide full ancestry in order to make the assignment without a potentially dangerous cast.

Comment: When I said: "share instances of class C", I meant returning a C*. My question is that if, by having a C* returned by the core, each library will find the functions they want since they don't know nothing about C.

Comment: That is not going to work. You need to provide a complete definition of `C` in order to return a pointer. If you return a `C*` which is just forward declared it will not run, and you will not be able to cast it to a `A` or `B` safely. It's either provice a `C` implementation or write two functions returning `A` or `B` respectively.

Comment: To be clear, you can only return a pointer to `C` if you provide either a forward declaration of `C`, or a full declaration. The forward declaration will be illegal to convert to either a B or a A.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, no. You're calling the same function in both cases; the only way that can work is for it to return `C*`. Than can only be converted to `A*` or `B*` if the definition of `C` is known (and it would also require the inheritance to be public).

If you have two separate functions, one returning `A*` and one returning `B*`, then that will be fine. Each base-class subobject contains enough information for virtual dispatch and RTTI to work correctly, without knowledge of the object's dynamic type.

Comment: X is supposed to be the same function. My question is that by having a C* passed by the core, each library will find the functions they want since they don't know nothing about C.

Comment: @user246100: In that case, my first paragraph answers your question - without a definition of `C` (and public inheritance), the function result can't be converted into a pointer to either base class.